# Sample sizes for differences between three groups

Tags: proportion, statistical-power, group-differences

I am doing a study of two schools, and at each school I am sampling three groups. I am trying to determine why the person chose to go to that school and not another. I will be asking each group various questions about the school and options they may  have had for other schools, etc. I want to be able to detect:

1. a difference of 20% in responses between the schools (e.g., proportion of students for whom current school was first school of preference, or proportion for whom there was no other choice), and
2. *within* each school, 20% difference in responses between the three different groups (similar questions, but for students who enrolled in different eras).

In both instances, I would like power of 80% for 0.05 significance.

So, if I do what I think is the appropriate calculation, I effectively come up with:
\begin{align} 
n &= \frac{0.5(0.84 + 1.96)^2}{0.2^2}  \\
  &= 98
\end{align}
Can I just assume then that I need three groups of 99 within each school? I guess I'm confused because nobody ever seems to talk about calculating sample sizes when comparing more than two groups.

Furthermore, is there anything wrong with sampling the three groups of 98 at each school and assuming that the total sample of 294 at each school will be sufficient to detect the 20% difference between the two schools?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a difference of 20%. There are three schools, so there are two differences (because once you know the first two, you know the third). In addition, power in this analysis depends on the proportions. You have more power if the proportion is around 50% than if it is around 1%.

Comment: Can you give an example of the effect you expect, e.g. 20%, 30%, 50%. Also, how do you plan to analyze?

Comment: Hello - thank you for your response.  I will try to clarify.  I will be asking students at each school if, for example, there was another school they could have attended, and the using chi2 tests to compare proportions at each.  Within each school, I will be using logistic regression to look at association between factors examined (e.g. option for other school) and school of choice.  I do not know what effect to expect.

Comment: In my calculations above, I simply assumed that 50% of population could have chosen a different school.  I had been told,I thought, that this would give a good sample size where such proportions are unknown?

Comment: So you're planning to do three separate logistic regressions? (Chi-square tests on contingency tables and logistic regression give the same answer). I'm still not sure what you are going to be testing (but maybe that's me). Can you give an example?

Comment: How are you dealing with multiple testing?

Comment: What software do you have access to?

Comment: It is not you, jeremy - I struggle to explain my thoughts in English :)  I am looking, for example, at a school in an area that has changed significantly in recent decades. I am looking at people who enrolled in that school at three different times and asking them why they chose that school: for example, they wanted to go elsewhere but could not afford, school was their first preference, etc.

Comment: All analysis is in STATA, though I think I can access SPSS